# Python Multithreading - Schedule Queue

Tags: python, multithreading

I don't know why I'm having such a problem with this, basically, I want to have a Queue that is constantly running during the program called "Worker" this then works, however, every 10 seconds or so.. Another method called "Process" comes in and processes the data. Let's assume the following, data is captured every 10 seconds.. (0, 1, 2, 3, ..... n) and then the "Proces" function receives this, processes the data, ends, and then the "Worker" goes back to work and does their job until the program has ended.

I have the following code:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import time

DELAY_SIZE = 10

def Worker(q):
    print "I'm working..."

def Process(q): 
    print "I'm processing.."

queue = mp.Queue(maxsize=DELAY_SIZE)
p = mp.Process(target=Worker, args=(queue,))

p.start()

while True:
  d = queue.get()
  time.sleep(10)
  Process()
```

In this example, it would look like the following:

```
I'm working...
I'm working...
I'm working...
...
...
...
I'm working...

I'm processing...
I'm processing...
I'm processing...
...
...

I'm working..
I'm working..
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What is the question exactly?

Comment: @RickyA I need to create a program that will allow for the "Worker" thread to gather data, and then every 10 seconds the "Process" will process the data.. This is repeated whilst "True".. Does it make sense?

Comment: Yes, makes sense, but what is wrong with your current code?

Comment: @RickyA It does not move past.. `I'm working...` Any ideas why?

Comment: Hi! You're not feeding the queue... You have to put results in the Worker (q.put(...)), so the q.get() blocks forever. But anyways, your code is not doing what you want ; why are you using multiprocessing and not threads?

Comment: @mguijarr - This seems to work: http://ideone.com/dZZEcl I don't know, could you possibly suggest an alternative way using threads?

Comment: Did you test the alternative with threads? Do you need more help?

Comment: @mguijarr Hey thanks for the reply. No. http://ideone.com/ArS4Ie it just seems to print "I'm working.." I don't understand where I'm going wrong. After each 10 seconds, the "process" should start running after 10 seconds.. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an alternative way using threads:

```
import threading
import Queue
import time

class Worker(threading.Thread):
  def __init__(self, q):
    threading.Thread.__init__(self)

    self._q = q

  def run(self):
    # here, worker does its job
    # results are pushed to the shared queue
    while True:
      print 'I am working'
      time.sleep(1)
      result = time.time() # just an example
      self._q.put(result)

def process(q):
  while True:
    if q.empty():
      time.sleep(10)
    print 'I am processing'
    worker_result = q.get()
    # do whatever you want with the result...
    print "  ", worker_result

if __name__ == '__main__':
   shared_queue = Queue.Queue()
   worker = Worker(shared_queue)
   worker.start()
   process(shared_queue)
```